# Explanation of the following program's output

Tags: c

Look at the program-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=2, y=6, z=6;
    x = y == z;
    printf("%d",x);
}
```

I thought the output would be 6. I think that z's value is 6 and z is equal to y. So y has the value 6. And the y(which value is 6) is assigned to x. So i think the answer should be 6. But upon execution I find that the the answer is 1. Can anybody explain, why 1 is the output of this program?

Comment: Google "C operator precedence"

Comment: Look Rashmi and Haccks. They have given the answer i want..Anyway thanks for ur comment.

Comment: It is a good question and a beginner is learning- I don't understand why all are interested in downvoting

Comment: @Rashmi Do you really think this question *shows research effort; it is useful and clear?* It shows no research effort at all.

Comment: @FilipeGoncalves Just because you have got more points, doen't mean you are genious. I am 100% sure, when you were a beginner and have learnt only bool, comparison operators, you won't be knowing how x has become bool when it is declared as int.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves You think i start to research without learning?? First i have to learn. IF i face problem i ask..Research is for intermediate level, isn't it?

Comment: @RottieRango Don't worry about downvoting people. Keep asking questions. That's the way to learn. :). Some have got bad habit of downvoting

Comment: @Rashmi Yp ur very kind..I don't care the damn downvoting..Thanks for staying beside a newbie.

Comment: @RottieRango; Research doesn't mean to become Phd student here. It means at least you should have to search it on the internet.

Comment: @Rashmi; *Just because you have got more points, doen't mean you are genious.*: May be. But it does mean that he is more experienced and trusted user on this website.

Comment: @haccks You have got more points than him. But you did answer to this question. I always see some people downvoting- just for fun. I am sure, they will also get struck at some point. Some questions, we might feel it silly.but doesn't mean you have to discourage others. How can someone learn without asking questions?

Comment: @haccks Look i don't want any quarrel here..Rashmi was just talking abt the dwonvoting..And Filipe talks about the research. If u want to go research u need to have some skills on it definetly more than the newbie. I still don't know what would be the best search result for me. I have to rely on question. If u don't interested to ask any of my question i don't care so. I may find others for answering my questions. Rashmi was not wrong i think. Downvoting is a nice option for pissed a newbie off. If u wanna answer some research related question, then i suggest u not to answer my question.

Comment: @Rashmi; *I always find some people likes to downvote* : Agreed. But @Filipe is correct on his stand. You can't deny that :). By the way, *you won't be knowing how x has become bool when it is declared as int.*, is wrong . `x` is still `int` here, not a `bool` type.

Comment: @RottieRango; *If u wanna answer some research related question, then i suggest u not to answer my question.*: Here, you again misunderstanding the word "research". "research effort" means at least   you should search about this on the web before asking this on SO. And about the line : *then i suggest u not to answer my question.*: Once you asked a question here then it becomes public, Mind it!

Comment: @haccks Man..I am kinda shocked that u tell me to research on internet but not in the SO first. Ok if ask a question to google first then it might not be appropriate. But when i answer a question to SO i might get the appropriate answer. You might think that searching answer on google is the research but making a question in SO is not the research..Ur thinking just impress me!!!!! Remember the question looks silly to u it's may not like this at all to the questioner. So i make a request to u if u think my question is not research based just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,
You are checking y==z. (y==z) will return a boolean value. So that will be true(1 in C, true in C#). thus the value 1.

Comment: I dont think x is treated as bool. 1 is still an integer value.

Comment: So 100 is char, short or int?

Comment: @Rashmi There is no such thing as `bool` in C. Relational operators yield an integer value that is either `0` or `1`.

Comment: @FilipeGoncalves - It is a boolean value. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Rashmi It's an integer. You can think of it as boolean if you find it easier, but technically, it's an integer. C treats it as an integer. You can have things like `(y == z) + 3`. For whatever it's worth, it's an integer. So stop being ignorant and listen to what other people tell you. And if you don't believe, grab a K&R copy and read it.

Answer (score 8):

`x = y == z;` is parsed by the compiler as `x = (y == z);` because of the [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)  of `==` is higher than that of `=` operator.
`y == z` checks whether `y` is equal to `z` or not and produce a Boolean value (either `0` or `1`) based on the result of comparison. Since `y = 6 = z`, `y == z` returns `1` causing the value of `x` to be `1`. Hence the output is `1`.

Comment: Sometimes I feel that I have been cheated.

Comment: It is funny to see the most up voted and elaborated answer isn't accepted.

Comment: @GovardhanReddy It depends who answered this first. But also depends on your total points. It is called `"reputation conspiracy"`.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment operator works from right to left. so `y == z` would be first executed. Double equals operator in c checks if both values are same or not. If they are it returns true which is nothing but 1 in c.

This value will then be copied to x. C doesn't have boolean data type it uses integers to store boolean. 1(or any non zero) means true and 0 means false.

if you expected to copy value of z to x, the below line would be more appropriate...

`x = y = z;` better yet `x = z;` would also work.

Comment: thanks..One of the appropriate answers

Answer (score 1):

Caveat, it's been a while since I've worked in c.

The initial assignments work as you expect.  `x=2`, `y=6`, and `z=6`.

The key is that `==` is a boolean equals operator.  So it basically asks does `y` equal `z`? True or false?  So your line evaluates in this order:

```
x = y == z;  // Does y equal z?  Evaluates to TRUE because 6 equals 6

x = TRUE;  //  TRUE casts to 1 as an int

x = 1;
```